# 特定カラムに対してLimit条件を指定してレコードを抽出したい

Tags: mysql, sql

LIMITを特定のカラムを基準に適応する事は可能でしょうか？

例として、以下のようなデータがあるとし同一idのレコードを2件ずつ抽出したいです。

**対象のデータ:**

| no | id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 太郎 |
| 2 | 1000 | 花子 |
| 3 | 1000 | 次郎 |
| 4 | 2000 | 太郎 |
| 5 | 2000 | 花子 |
| 6 | 3000 | 花子 |
| 7 | 4000 | 次郎 |
| 8 | 4000 | 花子 |
| 9 | 4000 | 次郎 |
| 10 | 4000 | 次郎 |

**希望する結果:**

| no | id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 太郎 |
| 2 | 1000 | 花子 |
| 4 | 2000 | 太郎 |
| 5 | 2000 | 花子 |
| 6 | 3000 | 花子 |
| 7 | 4000 | 次郎 |
| 8 | 4000 | 花子 |

※id=3000の場合、同一idのレコードが2件以上ないため、除外せずに1レコードだけでも上記のように表示させたいです。

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 8.0 であれば `ROW_NUMBER()` が利用できますので、

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual :: 12.21.1 Window Function Descriptions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number)

以下の様に書くことができます。

```sql
SELECT no, id, name FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY no) as ranking
  FROM member
) AS _ WHERE ranking <= 2;
```